# How do I start a React Website with HTTPS in production?

Tags: reactjs, https

Is it possible to serve a React Website in production with https?
In development this command starts the server with https

```
HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=cert.key npm start
```

but it doesn't seem to work when you try to serve the Project like this

```
sudo HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=cert.key serve -s build -l 80
```

am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to setup https in React without being in development and without using a virtual web server like apache?

Btw. I am using Ubuntu as my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production you don't want to serve your React app using Webpack. Instead you need to build the React app using `npm run build` then serve the contents of your `public` or `out` folder using a web server like Nginx/Apache.

To serve requests over HTTPS you then need to configure the web server with a SSL pem and chain key file and also possible upgrade all HTTP request to HTTPS. You can get free SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

Comment: I hoped it would be possible to serve React with https without Nginx or Apache.

Comment: You can serve your app from an AWS S3 bucket for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app or npx to create app. then build a production build with command `npm run build`.
It will produce a dist/ directory in project root directory.

You can use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to  create ssl certificate and nginx for hosting.

common nginx config will be something like

```
server {  listen 80;
  server_name yourdomain.com;
  server_name **.**.**.**; //your public ip
  root /var/apps/reactApp; //build directory
  index index.html;
   location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I now got it to work under apache but I used certbot for the ssl certificate.